# SSRS Parameter filtering using sql

Tags: sql, reporting-services

In Visual Studio 2012 S-S-R-S report , If in report I pass a filter parameter (say Department-Name) but while processing the report using S-Q-L query I want Department-ID as a filter in Where Clause...So how can you derive Department-ID from Parameter as Department-Name, without using sub or nested query.....as they wont work, and nor can add/display another parameter as Department-ID.

Comment: Why won't subselect work? Do you have a Department table that stores Department ID and Department Name? You could just join to this table and then filter on name? Or make your parameter a drop down list from this table, with DepartmentID as the value, and Department Name only for display purposes?

Comment: I tried that too, in valuefield =  dept Id, and in labelfield= Deptname ....and not expected result

Comment: Hey, garethD I got that, it was minimal problem that I neglected....and yeah ur solution was correct..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the parameter you created for DepartmentName corresponds to the parameter within the dataset.  If it does match, it should pass the parameter to the dataset.  That way having the ID of the DepartmentID and the Value of the DepartmentName, it should work for both values.

Your dataset procedure would get the ID rather than the label which is just for users. For more information look at:

[Paremeters in SSRS Reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)